# Math.Expectation And Variance of Stationary Series

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, expected-value, machine-learning, time-series

we have formula of  stationary time series
$$y_t = 0.6\cdot y_{t-1} + 2 + e_t$$
as mathematical expectation is constant, we can do the following:
$$E = 0.6\cdot E + 2 + 0$$
$$E = 5$$
Variance is $\sigma^2 = E(y_t^2)-(E(y_t))^2 = E(y_t^2)-25$

1. Is it correct?
2. How to calculate variance until the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean is correct. You can use the same methodology to compute the variance:$$\begin{align*}\sigma^2 &= V(y_t) \\&= V(0.6\cdot y_{t-1} + 2 + e_t) = 0.6^2\sigma^2 + V(e_t)\end{align*}.$$
Solving for $\sigma^2$ yields $\sigma^2=V(e_t)/0.64$

Comment: so there is not a number as Variance result, only formula?

Comment: I mean can we drop Var(e_t) somehow?

Comment: it depends on what $V(e_t)$ is. often $e_t\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ is assumed, thus $V(e_t) = 1$ then.

Comment: no, you cannot drop $V(e_t)$. Since $y_t$ depends on $e_t$ it is impossible to express the variance without $e_t$